# How to use permitDynamic stateless dotnet

Tags: c#, stateless-state-machine

I am tryingg to use stateless dotnet.

I need a transition to be condition on a string variable.

```
_machine.Configure(State.CalibSelectDisplay1)
            .Permit(Trigger.Up, State.CalibSelectDisplay2)
            .Permit(Trigger.Down, State.CalibSelectDisplay12)
            .Permit(Trigger.SC, State.Init)
            .PermitDynamic(Trigger.Enter, methodThatReturnsNewState(params));
```

but I get an error saying:

CS1503: Argument2: cannot convert from 'MS_Firmware.Firmware.State' to 'System.Func<MS_Firmware.Firmware.State'>

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
.PermitDynamic(Trigger.Enter, methodThatReturnsNewState(params));
```

on

```
.PermitDynamic(Trigger.Enter, () => methodThatReturnsNewState(params));
```